# What is the meaning of "от добра добра не ищут"?

Tags: узус, semantics, idioms

*От добра добра не ищут.*

Is its meaning the same as in

*Лучшее - враг хорошего?*

If not, are there any similar idioms in Russian which might clarify the meaning of the former phrase?

Answer (score 8):

I would say that they have roughly the same meaning with some nuances.

"*От добра добра не ищут*" usually refers to a complete change, which is too risky (such as changing job, place of living, place of studying, citizenship, changing the key elements of business such as personality of the management, market target, basic design and so on)

"*Лучшее враг хорошего*" usually refers to to minor improvements which may be good taken separately but have tendency to never end because of newer and newer ideas appearing and hamper normal production process. This may also refer to never-ending reconstruction and other pursuits for perfection.

Answer (score 6):

Нет, это не совсем одно и тоже.

[*От добра добра не ищут*](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%83%D1%82)

1. Получив нечто даром, не следует ожидать или требовать бо́́льшего. Чаще применяется к отношениям между людьми или к ситуации, на которую сложно повлиять.
2. Делая добро людям не надейся на благодарность в ответ.

*Лучшее - враг хорошего* - не сто́ит пытаться улучшить/доработать что-то, что уже работает хорошо. Чаще применяется к материальным вещам/процессам/технологиям, на которые можно легко повлиять и легко испортить, получив результат, обратный ожидаемому.

Comment: "От добра добра не ищут" чаще, по крайнеймере в народе, означает, что ты не всегда получишь благодарность от тех, кому сделал добро.

Comment: @Barafu Albino Спасибо, я не знал, что у этой поговорки есть другой смысл, добавил в ответ.

Comment: Совершенно неверно. Absolutely incorrect! "От добра добра не ищут" означает только одно - если у тебя есть что-то хорошее, не стоит это менять на что-то другое. Например, менять место работы или место жительства. Смысл, указанный в ответе - не верен! Особенно удивил второй вариант, такого смысла вообще быть не может, так как традиционная русская мораль учит, что благодарность всегда вознаграждается. -1000

Comment: Значение поговорки *от добра добра не ищут* я всегда представлял как сюжет в [Сказке о рыбаке и рыбке](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B5) А. С. Пушкина. Старуха не ценит того, что уже сделала для неё золотая рыбка и требует бо́льшего, в результате старуха остаётся у разбитого корыта. Второе значение для меня не совсем обычно, но я понимаю его смысл - делать добро бескорыстно. Переведя бабушку через дорогу, не жди, что она заплатит деньги, угостит конфетой или скажет спасибо.

Comment: @eugene да, к этой сказке поговорка применима, но не потому что она получила это даром, а потому что смена рискована - пытаясь найти лучшее можно потерять то, что есть! Для полученного даром есть поговорка "дареному коню в зубы не смотрят", вы, вероятно, с ней путаете. А второй смыл просто не существует (высосан из пальца).

Comment: Смысл поговорки не существует сам по себе, этот смысл вкладывают в неё люди. Я тоже не подозревал о другом понимании этой поговорки. Можно считать это ошибкой, а можно принять, что есть [другое толкование «от добра добра не ищут»](http://www.google.ru/search?q=значение+поговорки+от+добра+добра+не+ищут) и оно распространено, насколько широко - не знаю.

Comment: Funny. That new second meaning is a total surprise to me. I knew "Не делай добра - не получишь зла" but, as far as I remember, the usage of that proverb was on decline when I was in Russia. It looks like it finally died out and "от добра добра не ищут" started to creep into the vacuum thus formed (though the current meaning is not as pessimistic as that of the old proverb yet).

Comment: Literal understanding: “*when you're at something good (от добра), don't look for something good (не ищи добра)*”. It fits both interpretations. I have, too, never before met the second one, but it looks plausible enough. A rather common observation, too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that was precisely the interpretation<sup>*</sup> by Leo Tolstoy: he even wrote a short fable to illustrate it:

> Бежал заяц от собак и ушёл в лес. В лесу ему хорошо было, да уж много он страху набрался и хотел ещё лучше спрятаться. Стал искать, где поглуше место, и полез в чащу в овраге — и наскочил на волка. Волк схватил его. Видно, правда,— подумал заяц, что от добра добра искать не надо. Хотел лучше спрятаться и вовсе пропал. **(Л. Н. Толстой)**
>
> A rabbit ran away from a dog, and hid in the woods. He was safe there, but because he was scared so much, he decided to look for an even better hiding place. He ran into the thickets in the ravine, and got caught by a wolf. That's when the rabbit understood that one shouldn't try improving what's good: he wanted to hid better, but got caught instead.

Pushkin's well-known ["Видел я трех царей ..."](http://feb-web.ru/feb/pushkin/texts/selected/ppl/ppl-036-.htm) quote suggests that his interpretation has been identical to that of Tolstoy, that giving up what's good in exchange for what you perceive to be even better may carry significant risks. This meaning is close to "Лучшее - враг хорошего", which translates as "Perfect is the enemy of good", though it is not entirely the same: it implies that the current state is definitely not perfect, and that it does not address the risk aspect of searching for the perfection, which may or may not exist.

---

<sup>*</sup> Until today, I thought this was the only interpretation in existence.

Comment: +1. correct interpretation.

Comment: Wait a minute. The hare was a prey, right? That means the dogs, or their master, were meanining bad things for the hare. The literal meanining of the phrase is, roughly, 'don't expect good to be good', or 'don't expect any good from the good', but what is good there for the jackrabbit?

Comment: @Manjusri The good state for the hare was when he escaped the dogs, and hid in the woods: he was safely away from the dogs, but has not encountered the wolf yet.

Comment: Being russian, I never used it this way and suggest not to do it.

Comment: @kemerover Being Russian myself, I'd be rather curious to find out your interpretation of this saying?

Comment: eugene's point of you is close to mine.

Comment: @kemerover Which of eugene's two interpretations do you think it is, the "получив нечто даром", or the "не надейся на благодарность в ответ"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can translate both of them as "if it works, don't fix it."  Although, the more obvious one (лучшее - враг хорошего) is probably best seen as a justification for the first one rather than as its synonym.

Answer (score 0):

I would not agree with other interpretations. You should first understand what is `искать добро`. Which is similar to `seeking the truth`. Now `от добра` is different and means `in comfort`, `having happy life`, `being rich`, `having full house of goods`. So comfort living will not make you the truth seeker. This may confuse if you think that `добро` is used in same meaning twice, which is not exactly so. The context is normally mildly negative. It's like accusing someone (or self) of being lazy in a fancy philosophical way of saying.

I just realized you can say `with goods you won't seek for good` in english.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if you have already received good, trying to take even more may leave you with bare hands. This rabbit tried to hide even better, but lost his hiding place at all.